# Literal or resource file for non-user text

Tags: c#, resx

When writing libraries, I've taken to moving all my string literals to the resource file, even if they are something end users never see, and I don't have a need for translating the literal for other developers benefit (as the libraries are only developed by one team).

Recently someone doing a code review asked why I had put some strings for an exception message (which the end user will never see) into the resource file.  I assume because we know this string won't need to be translated.

I personally like it because I've found often times the string will be needed multiple places, and it ends up functioning the same way as a constant as the resx has a code file generated for me, so I don't need to maintain it myself.

I'd like to know if there are any standard conventions, best practices or offical guidelines.  Bear in mind that this is only for message like string, other strings that would be more appropriate as constants I do create as constants, so I'm only talking about exception messages or messages logged to something like log4net.

Comment: This is quite a subjective question; ultimately I'd say it comes down to a matter of style and/or in-house code guidelines.  There's no "right" or "wrong" answer.

Comment: I'm asking specifically if anyone knows if there are any industry guidelines or standard best practices which have been implemented.  If there aren't that will be an acceptable answer as well.  I'm not looking for people's opinions on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many benefits to using resources for string literals. I have often found out that they are great for aggregating error/success/validation messages. When a product is going to be completed, it is common practice to collect all the messages so you can train helpdesk to answer questions based on what users see.

To this end, resources provide an easy to access centralized resource to manage all your messaging to the end user.

Also, if you want to change the language used on a particular condition, it is much easier to change one resource location and affect the whole library/app. Otherwise you will need to do a find/replace, and a new developer thrown into a project may just update one place and miss the other locations.

Comment: I agree, but my question is more about are there accepted industry-wide best practices around consolidating these kinds of messages to resource files.

Comment: @Andy Since resource files are .net specific, I'm a not sure what you mean with industry-wide. I do not know of any standards that particularly refer to how literals are handled. Generally, DRY and good abstractions are the rationale behind the use of resource files.

Comment: I mean is it more or less documented as accepted as a best practice amongst the .Net development community, or are there any guidelines from MS.

Comment: Hmmm, Here's some guidelines for win store apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465241.aspx but it seems all other language is related mostly with localization and globalization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x.aspx